# gremlinpython client.submitAsync() fails when deployed to Azure as App Service

Tags: flask, azure-web-app-service, python-asyncio, gremlin, tinkerpop

I have a Python Flask app that I am able to run locally. I have been able to run it with python 3.8 and 3.9. When running locally the app is able to connect to both a local instance of Cosmos DB using the gremlin API, as well as an instance hosted on Microsoft Azure. When I or a coworker deploy the Flask app as an Azure App Service (python 3.8.6), we get an error when trying to query cosmos DB. The stack trace and code is below. I am not sure why I am getting

[TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'max_workers']

since ThreadPoolExecutor has default arguments for all of it's parameters.  I have attempted to specify workers when I initialize the gremlin client but it makes no difference. It looks like the client will default a number of workers anyways if no value is passed in. I have also specified workers for gunicorn when running on Azure, but it does not make a difference.  I am running on Windows when developing locally, but the App Service runs on Linux when deployed to Azure.  The Flask app does start fine and I can hit other flask endpoints that do not query Cosmos.

gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --workers=4 app:app

Stack trace:

```
  File "/tmp/8d9a55045f9e6ed/myApp/grem.py", line xxxx, in __init__
    res = self.call_graph(gremlin_query)
  File "/tmp/8d9a55045f9e6ed/myApp/grem.py", line xxxx, in call_graph
    callback = self.client.submitAsync(query)
  File "/tmp/8d9a55045f9e6ed/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/client.py", line 144, in submitAsync
    return conn.write(message)
  File "/tmp/8d9a55045f9e6ed/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/connection.py", line 55, in write
    self.connect()
  File "/tmp/8d9a55045f9e6ed/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/connection.py", line 45, in connect
    self._transport.connect(self._url, self._headers)
  File "/tmp/8d9a55045f9e6ed/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/aiohttp/transport.py", line 77, in connect
    self._loop.run_until_complete(async_connect())
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/tmp/8d9a55045f9e6ed/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/aiohttp/transport.py", line 67, in async_connect
    self._websocket = await self._client_session.ws_connect(url, **self._aiohttp_kwargs, headers=headers)
  File "/tmp/8d9a55045f9e6ed/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 754, in _ws_connect
    resp = await self.request(
  File "/tmp/8d9a55045f9e6ed/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 520, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/tmp/8d9a55045f9e6ed/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 535, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/tmp/8d9a55045f9e6ed/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 892, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/tmp/8d9a55045f9e6ed/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 999, in _create_direct_connection
    hosts = await asyncio.shield(host_resolved)
  File "/tmp/8d9a55045f9e6ed/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 865, in _resolve_host
    addrs = await self._resolver.resolve(host, port, family=self._family)
  File "/tmp/8d9a55045f9e6ed/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/resolver.py", line 31, in resolve
    infos = await self._loop.getaddrinfo(
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 825, in getaddrinfo
    return await self.run_in_executor(
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 780, in run_in_executor
    executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'max_workers'
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask
Flask-SQLAlchemy
Flask-WTF
Flask-APScheduler
python-dateutil
azure-storage-file-share
gremlinpython
openpyxl
python-dotenv
python-logstash-async
futures
```

Gremlin Client Initialization

```
    self.client = client.Client(end_point,
                                'g',
                                username=username,
                                password=password,
                                message_serializer=serializer.GraphSONSerializersV2d0()
                                )
```

Send Query To Gremlin, this line causes the Exception

```
callback = self.client.submitAsync(query)
```

Comment: You may want to add a tag for either `gremlin` or `tinkerpop` to the question. That will probably get the attention of more people likely to know the answer. I could not make the edit for you as you can only have up to 5 tags and I would have had to delete one of yours.

Answer (score 2):

I got by this issue by creating a new requirements.txt by executing `pip freeze > requirements.txt` against my local code. I then deployed my application with the updated file. I am thinking that azure might have been providing me with a different version of aiohttp that was not compatible with python 3.8.6 but I am not sure. In any case, providing all of these dependency definitions got me by my issue.  Hopefully this helps someone else down the road.

```
aenum==2.2.6
aiohttp==3.7.4
APScheduler==3.8.0
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==21.2.0
azure-core==1.16.0
azure-cosmos==4.2.0
azure-functions==1.7.2
azure-storage-blob==12.8.1
azure-storage-file-share==12.5.0
certifi==2021.5.30
cffi==1.14.6
chardet==3.0.4
click==8.0.1
colorama==0.4.4
cryptography==3.4.7
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-APScheduler==1.12.2
gremlinpython==3.5.1
idna==2.10
isodate==0.6.0
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.1
limits==1.5.1
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
msrest==0.6.21
multidict==5.1.0
neo4j==4.3.2
nest-asyncio==1.5.1
oauthlib==3.1.1
openpyxl==3.0.7
pycparser==2.20
pylogbeat==2.0.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==0.19.0
python-logstash-async==2.3.0
pytz==2021.1
PyYAML==5.4.1
requests==2.25.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
six==1.16.0
tornado==6.1
typing-extensions==3.10.0.0
tzlocal==2.1
urllib3==1.26.6
Werkzeug==2.0.1
yarl==1.6.3
```

Comment: Confirming that this fix still works today for Python Azure Functions connecting to Gremlin CosmosDB instances.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that client.submitAsync(query) has been changed to client.submit_async, see https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-python/src/main/python/gremlin_python/driver/client.py

```
 def submitAsync(self, message, bindings=None, request_options=None):
    warnings.warn(
        "gremlin_python.driver.client.Client.submitAsync will be replaced by "
        "gremlin_python.driver.client.Client.submit_async.",
        DeprecationWarning)
    return self.submit_async(message, bindings, request_options)

def submit_async(self, message, bindings=None, request_options=None):
    ...
```